# Firefox 40.0.3 (Windows) not working with font-family

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I have the following CSS directive:

```
body {
    font-family: system, -apple-system, ".SFNSDisplay-Regular", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Calibri", sans-serif !important;
}
```

In Firefox 40.0.3 for Windows, the font displayed is an aliased (jagged) version of Arial:

[image: Snapshot in Windows]

In Firefox 40.0.3 for Mac OS X, the text is rendered correctly:

[image: Snapshot in OS X]

If I remove the Apple system font portion of the CSS, then the Windows version of Firefox works better and uses a typeface available to Windows that can be rendered correctly (either Calibri or whichever anti-aliasable sans serif that is available to Firefox):

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Calibri", sans-serif !important;
}
```

Instead of using a platform- or user-agent-specific CSS file, is there a way to modify the CSS so that Firefox under Windows ignores the portion of the `font-family` directive it doesn't like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed up with the following directive:

```
body {
    font-family: ".SFNSDisplay-Regular", -apple-system, "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Calibri", sans-serif !important;
}
```